# Barplot of categorical variables in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

From the documentation here: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/categorical_variables.html?highlight=plotting%20categorical%20variables it claims that

> Many times you want to create a plot that uses categorical variables in Matplotlib. Matplotlib allows you to pass categorical variables directly to many plotting functions, which we demonstrate below.

I won't include their code here, but here's something similar to my own:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'numerical_name': [str(x**2) for x in range(10)], 
                   'percents': [x*10 for x in range(10)]})
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(df['numerical_name'], df['percents'])
plt.show()
```

This perfectly mirrors the example that they give, as far as I can tell. They make it seem that `ax.bar()` can accept a list/array of strings as the first value. However, I am given this error:

> left = [left[i] - width[i] / 2. for i in xrange(len(left))]
>   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'

This seems like a bug/error in documentation to me, unless someone can see something obviously wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the answer: I needed to upgrade my version of matplotlib. Just run `pip install --upgrade matplotlib` and it worked just fine.

Comment: Please edit this answer to specify which version of matplotlib did you had before you upgraded

Comment: Afaik this feature was introduced in `matplotlib` 2.1. It definitely didn't exist in 1.5